# Python - Kivy manually refresh or reload the UI after a certain action is taken

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

Is there any way to manually reload all the UI elements in the application?
For example i change the color of an element inside the config.ini and i want it to take effect but the on_config_change callback seems to not do it. Is there any way to do this any other way?

Note: Restarting the whole application works but is not an option.

This is the code of the settings color:

```
class ColorPickerContent(FloatLayout):
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def _cancel(self):
        return self.cancel()

    def _save_color(self, hex_code):
        AppConfigs().config.set('section1', 'text_color', hex_code)
        AppConfigs().config.write()
        return self.cancel()


class SettingButtons(SettingItem):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_release')
        super(SettingItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for aButton in kwargs["buttons"]:
            oButton = Button(text=aButton['title'], font_size='15sp')
            oButton.ID = aButton['id']
            self.add_widget(oButton)
            oButton.bind(on_release=self.On_ButtonPressed)

    def set_value(self, section, key, value):
        # set_value normally reads the configparser values and runs on an error
        # to do nothing here
        return

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def On_ButtonPressed(self, instance):
        content = ColorPickerContent(cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Get Color", content=content,
                            size_hint=(1, 1), auto_dismiss=True)
        self._popup.open()
```